# Voltage drop across an ideal voltmeter and ammeter

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

What is the voltage drop across an ideal voltmeter and an ideal ammeter in a circuit?

Answer (score 1):

An ideal voltmeter theoretically has infinite internal impedance and thus the voltage across the voltmeter equals the actual voltage that exists between the two points if the voltmeter were not present.

An ideal ammeter theoretically has zero internal impedance and thus the current measured by the ammeter equals the actual current in the circuit that exists if the ammeter were not present.

Of course, as already pointed out, ideal voltmeters and ammeters do not exist.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

On a voltmeter the voltage drop is what it says, on an ammeter it depends on the current and the inner resistance.  "ideal" ammeter does not exist, it would have no resistance and so no voltage drop.